# I have some dedicated servers running NGINX and Docker. Where is NGINX located on my server? Or is it running virtually somewhere?

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, docker

I have four servers running web apps with different domains and subdomains with a Docker git Linux stack. Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and I can't figure out no matter how hard I look where NGINX is installed?  Any suggestion are greatly appreciated.

Comment: What did you use to install `nginx`?

Comment: Hi Paul. I hired a freelancer but the service I use to chat with DevOps has latency issues and messages are not getting through. So I usually could ask the DevOps staff this.  I have a meeting finally after waiting a week to hear from them.  The meeting is in 1 hour or so.  I'll ask that question and share the answer.  Thanks for the query!

Comment: Kindly share more details how it's installed, diagram, code, stack etc.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.